# ReactJS: detect the status of axios calls from within a component

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, components, axios

In my `React` component, I have many `axios` calls to retrieve data from the server, as well as a `Validate` button that confirms the form.

The behaviour I want is to keep the `Validate` button disabled while the axios calls haven't completed yet.

I don't want to go through every axios call and add a `then` clause to update a state that would say if the WS completed yet, because I want the solution to be maintainable.

Is there a way to detect within my component if my axios calls are still on progress? Also note that my axios calls are common to many other components, so I really need to detect if one *specific component* made the *axios call*.

Comment: can you post an example of one of the calls. do the calls change anything on the page/DOM?

Comment: Yes, the ajax calls retrieve data that populate the state, and hence, React changes the DOM accordingly.